# Looking for verses to the refrain of "Hoch sollst du leben"

Tags: lyrics

From my childhood in the 90s I remember that we used a song for the birthday celebrations at my elementary school that had the classic "Hoch sollst du leben" birthday song as a refrain and had two or three verses. I think it was played from a tape but it could have been a CD or even vinyl record as well.

I think I remember the melody accurately but the text has holes in my mind. So now I'm trying to find the text or a recording or any hint which specific rendition of "Hoch sollst du leben" this was. I've tried googling but no results that come anywhere close to what I remember. Here is how I think the song went:
[image: sheet music]

I think the missing text in the middle might be something like "und geht vielleicht bei dir das Glück mal aus, dann mach dir gar nichts daraus. Ja, ja, ja ..." but that sounds a bit clumsy so I probably misremember some details of the wording and this bit might well be from another verse.

Comment: Isn't the verse of that “Wie schön dass du geboren bist, Wir hätten dich sonst sehr vermisst; Wie schön dass wir beisammen sind, Wir gratulieren dir, Geburtstagskind” or am I mixing this up? That's at any rate a quite different melody from the sheet you posted.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - that's a different birthday song, there's more than one.  Here in Vienna we sing both, along with "Heppy Birzday too yoo".